# Transfer Files from one s3 Folder to Another s3 Folder using Boto3 Python

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to copy files from one s3 bucket to another with some modifications in destination path.

The Original Script is as below:

```
import boto3
import os
old_bucket_name = 'XT01-sample-data'
old_prefix = 'Test/'
new_bucket_name = 'XT02-sample-data2'
new_prefix = old_bucket_name + '/' + old_prefix
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
ENCRYPTION = os.environ.get('SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION', 'AES256')
STORAGE_CLASS = os.environ.get('STORAGE_CLASS', 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING')
old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name)
new_bucket = s3.Bucket(new_bucket_name)
extra_args = {
                'ServerSideEncryption': ENCRYPTION,
                'StorageClass': STORAGE_CLASS
              }

for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
    old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
                   'Key': obj.key}
    # replace the prefix
    new_key = obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix, 1)
    new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
    print("Object old ", obj)
    print("new_key ", new_key)
    print("new_obj ", new_obj)
    new_obj.copy(old_source,ExtraArgs=extra_args)

print("Starting Deletion Loop")
bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name)
bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix).delete()
```

The above script is copying the files from bucket XT01-sample-data, Folder Test/
to New bucket XT02-sample-data2 with new path XT01-sample-data/Test1/

The ask is now to modify the script to add timestamp in destination path and files from one folder lands under once time stamp.

Eg:
We have below files in source bucket at various folders

```
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test1.1/File1.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test1.1/File2.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test1.1/File3.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test1.2/File1.2.1.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test1.2/File1.2.2.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test1.3/File1.3.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/Test2/Test2.1/File2.1.csv
```

**Expected output** should be all files from one subfolder should be placed under one timestamp.
not all files should be placed in one timestamp there should be a level of segregation based on Timestamp at milisecond level (unix timestamp)

---

**For Files under folder Test1/Test1.1**

```
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0000/File1.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0000/File2.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0000/File3.csv
```

---

**For files under folder Test1/Test1.2**

```
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0003/File1.2.1.csv
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0003/File1.2.2.csv
```

---

**For files under folder Test1/Test1.3**

```
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0004/File1.3.csv
```

---

**For files under folder Test1/Test2/Test2.1**

```
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/0005/File2.1.csv
```

---

Comment: It looks like you are adding more than just a timestamp in your expected output. What is the `0000`, `0003`, `0004` and `0005` supposed to be?

Comment: Hi Mark B 0000, 0004 is timestamp at ms level

Comment: So you just want year/month/date/millisecond? That could possibly overlap with the same value once per second.

Comment: To be clear you want to replace the last "subfolder" in the old key with `year/month/day/millisecond`?

Comment: @MarkB: yes correct. year/month/day/millisecond.

Comment: it should be like this:   

For files under folder Test1/Test2/Test2.1
XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/142243/File2.1.csv

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For files under folder Test1/Test1.3

XT01-sample-data/Test1/2020/01/23/142250/File1.3.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making an entry in dynamodb table.
Logic:

```
 as soon as the first instance is encountered then entry is made in dynamodb table.
```

when next instance is encountered a corresponding check is made in dynamodb table before copying the data and same date which is present in dynamodb is taken.